# How to forward my application on login activity after pressing on logout button?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on android application i want to know 
How to forward my application on login activity after pressing on logout button from another activity ?

Comment: finish() your previous activities and run LoginActivity

Comment: call your login activity through Intent..simple.

Comment: passes intent to another activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your concern

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

For ex: Say you have back button named "back"

```
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use intent service.

Here is the best example of login:

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/

Answer (score 0):

Call your login activity by

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

you can clean the app data by using the following code

```
/**
 * Call this method to delete any cache created by app
 * @param context context for your application
 */
public static void clearApplicationData(Context context) {
    File cache = context.getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            File f = new File(appDir, s);
            if(deleteDir(f))
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("**************** DELETED -> (%s) *******************", f.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }
}
private static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            System.exit(0);
```